# What does the paladin spell list hold for an already versatile caster?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, spells, cleric, paladin

I am considering playing a cleric//wizard gestalt character in an upcoming campaign set in Eberron. I haven't picked a race, but I'm considering taking, on the wizard side, the prestige class silver pyromancer (*Five Nations* 150-4) because I think that class's access to paladin spells is interesting. However, I'm not not well versed in the paladin spell list and don't know how much overlap exists between the spells I'd already be able to cast and the paladin spells I'd be able to gain.

Given my character's already large pool of spells from which he can draw, does the silver pyromancer's ability to add paladin spells to a wizard's spellbook bring any significant spells to the table? That is, are there paladin spells that have effects **both** that can't be duplicated by cleric spells (short of *miracle*) and wizard spells (short of *wish et al.* and *shadow conjuration et al.*) **and** that provide significant offense, defense, or utility, or that are wholly unique?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. An interesting question the site may not be equipped to handle as an answer will likely be list-based, opinion-based, *and* broad. However, given the character's already vast array of spells, paladin spells that *don't* duplicate what wizard and cleric spells are capable of may be narrow enough to be answerable. I encourage you to add the character's race, level, available resources, and fellow party members, and the campaign's gist and allowed resources so any answer can be more precise. No matter what, thank you for participating.

Comment: “Good” is no better than “cool”. I understand that you might not be able to put it more objectively, but that just might mean you have a question that doesn't fit our site's purpose. If you do just want people's opinions, we're the wrong site for that but we can [point you to some discussion forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) where that kind of discussion is permitted.